# How to remove ScrollStep jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using [this](http://amondit.github.io/jquery.scrollsteps.js/jquery.scrollsteps.js.demo.html) plugin to make my page scrolling in a step. The function to initiate the plugin is:

```
    $("body").scrollsteps({
        up: prev,
        down: next
    });

    function pageScroll(element, position) {

    var translation = "translate3d(0,"+(-(position))+"px,0)"
    $(element).css({
        'transform': translation,
        '-webkit-transform': translation,
        '-moz-transform': translation,
        '-o-transform': translation,
        '-ms-transform': translation
    });
}

function next(e){
  if(!(currentPageIndex == (numberOfPages - 1))){
        currentPageIndex++;
        pageScroll("body",currentPageIndex * pageHeight);
    }
}
function prev(e){
    if(!(currentPageIndex == 0)){
        currentPageIndex--;
        pageScroll("body",currentPageIndex * pageHeight);
    }
}
```

What I want to do is to remove that scrolling step using jquery. Is there any way to remove it like :

```
$("body").scrollsteps("destroy");
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the source code : https://github.com/amondit/jquery.scrollsteps.js/blob/gh-pages/jquery.scrollsteps.js

You can try this :

```
$("body").off('mousewheel', false);
```